# Does Unitary must have norm equal to 1?

Tags: operator-theory

Does Unitary must have norm equal to 1?

I know U is unitary then $UU^*=I$, so $\|Ux\|^2=(Ux,Ux)=(U^*Ux,x)=(x,x)$, so $\|U\|=1$. Is this a proof?

Comment: Yes. You just showed that $\|Ux\|=\|x\|$ for all $x$, so $U$ has indeed operator norm one. It's also an isometry.

Answer (score 4):

You should note what norm you are using (the matrix-$2$-norm $\|U\|_2$). Practically this is correct, though because it shows
$$\| Ux \|_2 = \|x\|_2 \Rightarrow \frac{\|U x\|_2}{\|x\|_2} = 1 \Rightarrow \|U\|_2 = \sup_{x\ne 0} \frac{\|U x\|_2}{\|x\|} = 1$$

Comment: If $U$ is a linear operator between infinite dimensional normed spaces, how does the $2$-norm look like?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Can you specify some space you are interested in? The supremum definition „lifts“ a norm from a space to its dual.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase my question. You note that you should specify the norm, but how does the 2-norm look in a infinite dimensional normed space, or does this result doesn't hold in those spaces? Obviously, if we are on Hilbert spaces, we can choose the norm induces by the scalar product, but what do we do in the other cases?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik What about $L^2$? Or do you explictly want to look at an infinite-dimensional non-Hilbert space? NB that unitary operators are by definition between two hilbert spaces.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question.